# How to constantly test for a something?

Tags: python

So basically, in my text-based game, there is a variable (health) that means the players, well, health. There are multiple obstacles in the game that can harm the player and take away health. I am wondering how to make it so that the code constantly checks if the heath is zero. If it is, I want it to print 'You died!' And end the game. Otherwise, to continue on with the game. Thanks in advance.

Code can be seen here: https://repl.it/LUL5/36

Comment: Looking at your code, a few things instantly come to mind:
- write a Player class, that will stably hold all the Player's info (including health) instead of using global variables
- write a Level class, that is instantiated each time that you `end` a week

Comment: You can check the health whenever some action affects it. However, I'd also suggest restructuring your code first and centralizing state changes, rather than modifying multiple global variables in many different parts of your code.

Comment: You have too many while loops. Instead of saying 'while health == 0' have a massive 'while true' and inside of it, check the health using an if statement e.g. 'if health == 0'